# heroku pg password authentication failed error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cedar

I'm a total heroku noob so please bear with me on this one. Last night I deployed an application to heroku cedar, putting 'gem 'pg'' into the production group on my gemfile and leaving sqlite3 in my development and test groups.

Everything was working fine last night, today I went to show it off and got a 500 error. My local dev environment is peachy. I looked at my logs and I find that it's a 'PG::Error Authentication Failed'. Same problem on the heroku production console. The authentication is failing for a pg user that I'm assuming is being generated for heroku. Thoughts?

Comment: Heroku just had a massive system failure a few days ago due to an electrical storm.  I'd wait and see if the error persists.  It may be that they are just fixing things up temporarily. Although, it does say they are fully opperational: https://status.heroku.com/

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app? heroku restart --app=yaddayadda

Comment: Heroku restart isn't changing anything. And yeah, I considered whether  or not heroku was down, but it says it's up.

Comment: Have you worked through their support page? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database

Answer (score 0):

Screw it, I just destroyed the application and made a new one. I figure with all the problems heroku had this weekend, it might just be something related to that. Redoployed, and it's working so far...